# What could I combine with a Jalapeno/Serrano to approximate the taste of a Habanero?

Tags: chili-peppers

I have 6 Habaneros in my Chili recipe as I quite like the subtle fruity flavor that they give to it in the end when combined with everything else. Unfortunately, my midwest US supermarkets tend to not carry or be out of stock of them almost constantly, so I'd like to find something that I can reliably fall back on should the need arise.

Is there anything common that I could combine with Jalapenos or Serranos that would approximate that fruitiness? I'm not too concerned about the heat level.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think that you are going to be able to reproduce the flavor of habaneros with other peppers.  Jalapeños and serranos both have fairly distinct flavors (I find both to be pleasantly bitter, in comparison to the fruitier, more floral flavor of a habanero).  You can definitely get the *heat* of a habanero in other words (cayenne powder will get you close, for example), but I don't see how you get the other flavors.

Comment: Aren't Habaneros a bit like Scotch Bonnets? We can't get habaneros here in the UK, though you can get bonnets in any supermarket/grocery, so I've never been able to compare directly.

Comment: @Tetsujin habaneros and scotch bonnets are so close that some people argue they're the same pepper.  But it sounds like the OP needs to make do with jalopenos where they live.

Comment: @Tetsujin Indeed, I've read the same, but those are even harder to find in my area. I'm pretty much limited to jalapenos, serranos, and poblanos.

Comment: Ah, OK. Wish you luck. We have the opposite problem here, 'named' chillies are Bird's Eyes, Scotch Bonnets & in recent years Padrons; everything else is just a vague description - finger chillies, thin chillies, red chillies… who knows what type;) [Here's an example](https://groceries.asda.com/search/chillies?cmpid=ahc-_-ghs-_-asdacom-_-hp-_-search-chillies)

Comment: The supermarkets in my area are terribly inconsistent with stocking Scotch Bonnets, which are very similar to Habaneros. So I tend to buy mine, in bulk, online. Then I make either fermented chili sauce (which you can keep for a long time in a jar in the fridge, assuming the PH is low enough) or I store them in the freezer, in a good zip lock back or clip-lock container. They keep extremely well and work out much cheaper than supermarket prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fruity flavors of habanero are [frequently described as "citrusy"](https://www.chilipeppermadness.com/chili-pepper-types/hot-chili-pepper-types/habanero-chili-pepper/) and "sweet".  Assuming that you don't have other hot peppers available, I would try combining the following elements in different proportions until you get the flavor you're looking for:

- Fruity ripe bell peppers (seasonal)
- Tangerine juice
- Orange or tangerine zest
- Ripe, sweeter carrots (also seasonal)
- Small amounts of additional sugar

Comment: If habanero is "citrusy", adding some [aji limón](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_drop_pepper) chillies to your substitute would be interesting - but I've never seen them for sale. They're lemon yellow as well as having a citrus flavour, and grow well for me.

Comment: Chris: one can buy them canned in more gourmet stores.  However, I don't expect that the OP has that option either if they can't get habaneros.

Comment: Yes, and growing your own isn't exactly a quick substitute. But capsicum baccatum varieties grow very easily, more so than typical capsicum anuum for me, and they freeze well

Comment: My instinct was a bit of lemon or lime juice, so I'm glad I wasn't THAT far off. I'll try your suggestions, thank you!

Comment: Tock: YW.  The specific suggestions above are based on my taste buds.  I like habaneros, and those are the flavor elements I pick out -- like, it's more "tangerine" than "lime".  You'll find out if you agree.